# converting a list consist of decimal numbers to binary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary

I have a list of decimal numbers as integers, and I want to convert them into binary. The output must be without `0b` prefix and also it must be 4 digits
like:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
listres = [0001,0010,0011,0100,...]
```

*thanks in advance*

Comment: You mean you want to convert them to **strings**, right?

Comment: @roganjosh decimal as in decimal base, I suppose.

Comment: @roganjosh no worries ;)

Comment: What if the input list contains the number 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another hacky way to achieve this is:

```
listres = [str(bin(x))[2:].zfill(4) for x in lista]
```

Comment: the result of your code is string binary digits : ['0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101'] but how can I obtain integer as result like : [0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` with `format` here, with `'04b'`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: format(x,'04b'),lista))
['0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001', '1010']
```

Comment: just like the above answer, the result of your code is string binary digits : ['0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', '0101'] but how can I obtain integer as result like : [0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101]

Comment: You can't, those aren't integers if they're zero padded.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework, so I'll just give a recommendation on how to proceed in creating the second list. If you know how to convert an integer into a binary representation, then you can use a list comprehension:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
listb = [integer_to_binary(n) for n in lista]
```

Here integer_to_binary() is just a function that converts an integer into its binary representation. It sounds like what you want is a string showing the binary representation, so I'll leave that to you to figure out (hint: try using format())

Comment: no its not a homework. but thanks for recommendation

Answer (score -1):

Use bin method;

```
>>> a = bin(6)
>>>a

'0b110'
a[2:]
110
```